# Stairs and trim

Tags: stairs, trim, carpentry

My wife and I decided to update our upstairs trim to a white after finishing the basement that way. I've run into a problem with the laminate stairs. Prior to the white, the trim was stained a dark brown so the small gaps between the laminate stairing and the trim wasn't noticeable. Well, now there are plenty of noticeable small gaps with the darker laminate against the white trim. What's the best way to go about handling this?[image]

Answer (score 3):

Caulk it in and wipe of any excess with a slightly damp sponge so the latex caulk is only in the gap, nothing smeared on the surface to make the caulk/gap seem bigger than it is.

Comment: I was thinking that's my best bet. That's what I just finished up doing with all the trim I installed in the basement. Just wasn't sure if it would be noticeable for anyone else with it being on another plane.

Comment: When the latex caulk is used, it will shrink a noticeable bit in the larger gaps. Not so bad for the verticals, but it will be noticeable at the treads, only because you will know they are there to begin with. Because they will shrink they will hold dust. You could go for another caulking, but the eye overall will not pick up on the gaps anymore. Only when you are "looking" for them will they be noticeable.